# Heckman correction for correlation estimates

Tags: correlation, linear-model, selection-bias, heckman

Suppose I observe random $y_{i,1}, y_{i,2}$, and I wish to estimate the correlation between them.
However, the $y_{i,j}$ are observed subject to some sample selection criterion.
That is,
there are some observed covariates $x_{i,1}, \ldots, x_{i,k}$ and an unobserved variable $z_i$ such that
we only see the $y_{i,j}$ if $f\left(x_{i,1}, \ldots, x_{i,k}, z_i\right) > 0$,
otherwise we do not observe the values of the $y_{i,j}$.
(For simplicity assume the $f$ is linear in its arguments.)
My questions:

1. Is the sample Pearson correlation biased or inefficient for estimating the correlation of the $y$? I suspect that if the $y_{i,j}$ are independent of the $x_{i,j}$ and $z_i$, there is no problem, but in general I assume there is a bias.
2. Can one use Heckman correction, or some other technique, to improve estimation of the correlation?

Comment: Experimentation indicates that there can be some bias when $y$ are linear in the $x$, for example. Moreover, when the $y$ are independent of the $x$, it seems that the sample correlation is unbiased.

Comment: Clarification needed: the "positivity" criterion does not use index j, so does that mean that if the condition is true, then both y_{i,1} and y_{i2} are observed?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.